# How to use Objective C lib in Xamarin Studio or IQKeyobardManager in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, shared-libraries

I am new to Xamarin so is it possible to use objective c lib in xamarin studio and how? or  how to use shared library in xamarin? or how to use this lib in xamarin studio. https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

Comment: thanks. its very helpful but i found this much easier to understand. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/